# create python excel cells from user input

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to take input from the user using tkinter. It asks for a number. I then want to take that number and create the amount of excel cells. I have my "excelcells" function working on its own but when im trying to take variable x as a number and convert it into a list i get conversion errors that i cant get past.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

Label(window, text='Number of Cells').grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(window)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
get = e1.get()
numfinal = int(get)


x = []

for i in range(0,int(numfinal)):
    x.append(i)

def excelcells(x):
    height = 1
    for i in range(height):
        for j, val in enumerate(x):
            b = Entry(window)
            b.insert(0, val)
            b.grid(row=i, column=j)
        window.mainloop()


Button(window, text='Create', command=excelcells(x)).grid()

window.mainloop()
```

This is the error i get "could not convert string to float: 'get'"

How can i pass the x list to my "excelcells" function when the create button is clicked? and convert the input given to the entry window from a string to an int?

part2:

How do i convert get variable from a string to an int?

current error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: `float('get')`?Or do you mean `float(get)`?

Comment: `command=excelcells(x)` should be `command=lambda: excelcells(x)`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432   for at least part of the problem.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA yeah sorry that was a previous mistake. It still throws an error with get

Comment: my issue is how do i convert get from a string to an int? my error with 

Label(window, text='Number of Cells').grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(window)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
get = e1.get()
numfinal = int(get)


x = []

for i in range(0,int(numfinal)):
    x.append(i)

error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: The problem isn't _how_ you're doing it, it's _when_ you're doing it. You're trying to convert the data well before the user even sees the entry widget, much less type into it.

Answer (score 1):

you have several problems here.
first, the command in

`Button(window, text='Create', command=excelcells(x)).grid()`

should be a function, and writing `excelcells(x)` actually calls the function and not passing it. (can be done with `command=lambda x: excelcells(x)` but it's not really what you want here)

Now, the problem that causes the error is that this bit:

```
get = e1.get()
numfinal = int(get)
```

is done sequentially right after creating the entry and therefore you are reading before the program had a chance to get to the window.mainloop() which pops up the window and waits for user interaction.

Third problem is that you call mainloop within the function, which will cause unwanted behavior later.

So to conclude, I believe that what you want is something like that:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

Label(window, text='Number of Cells').grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(window)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

def excelcells():
    get = int(e1.get())
    for i in range(get):
        b = Entry(window)
        b.insert(0, i)
        b.grid(row=i+2, column=0)


Button(window, text='Create', command=excelcells).grid()

window.mainloop()
```